# Make a DAO injection in a thread

Tags: java, multithreading, jpa, wildfly, java-ee-7

I am developing a web application in java ee with wildfly, I have to develop a web service that responds immediately to the client, but you have to create a task or a thread to perform some tasks and finally update a record in the database

This is a basic example, here the thread is created

```java
@GET
@Path("/createReq")
@Produces("application/json")
public void createReq() {
    objThread trip = new ObjThread();
    trip.setIdTrip("id");
    trip.start();
}
```

This is a basic example, here the thread is created

```java
public class ObjThread extends Thread {
    volatile boolean ejecutar = true;
    public String idTrip;
    private int time = 0;

    @Inject
    Tbl_car_tripDAO tripDAO;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (ejecutar) {
                if (time == 1) { 
                    // task 1
                } else if (time ==  3) { //30
                    // task 2
                } else if (time >= 5) { //45
                    // task 3
                    detener();
                    changeStatus();
                }
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                time++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public void detener() {
        ejecutar = false;
    }

    public void changeStatus() {
        try {
            Tbl_car_trip trip= tripDAO.getTripByIdTrip(idTrip);
            trip.setCar_tri_status("data");
            tripDAO.update(trip);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }

    public void setIdTrip(String idTrip) {
        this.idTrip = idTrip;
    }
}
```

But at the time of execution I get a persistence error in the changeStatus method, but if I use the same method with the @inject annotation in another class, it works correctly.Could you please help me with this problem with a recommendation. Thank you

Updagrade

This is my DAO class

```
@Singleton
public class Tbl_car_tripDAO {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

    public boolean update(Tbl_car_trip tbl_car_trip) {
        try {
            em.merge(tbl_car_trip);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the ObjThread must be a Spring bean so you can inject the dependency (Tbl_car_tripDAO).

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class ObjThread extends Thread {
```

You will need to obtain the ObjThread from the Sprint context (cannot instantiate with new ObjThread ()

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation @Beppe C, but I would have to integrate spring into my project, because my project has no spring, would that cause any problems? Thank you

Comment: Oh I see, you use the Java EE injection (sorry, I read it too quickly).

The same applies to Java EE, you should be able to define your class as bean managed by the Java CDI context, maybe with @Singleton?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I implemented it but the error persists, it occurred to me to getter and seeter of the tripDAO attribute and the task was done correctly, I thank you for your help, but I don't know if that is the best way to implement a DAO.